# fixed field width for float python

Tags: python, formatting, field

I'm wondering how to print a float with fixed field width.
For example I want a float to be outputted on 3 digits maximum.

```
10.2 -> 10
0.25 -> 0.2
```

Thanks for your help.

Ch.

Comment: So you are saying you would want `1000 -> 100`?

Comment: I've checked but didn't find any answers to that question. Rudziankou is right. Let's suppose only numbers < 1000 and > 0